# Getting the index of a ComboBox in in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` in which one column has only ComboBoxes. When something changes in a ComboBox, I need to know what the new item is, and the row index of the ComboBox in which the event took place. The latter is giving me trouble. I have the following:

```
class MyForm : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView m_GridView;
    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn m_ComboBoxColumn;

    public MyForm () 
    {
      /* ... lots of initialisation stuf...*/
      this.m_GridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
                                       this.m_ComboBoxColumn});
    }

    private void m_GridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= new EventHandler(m_ComboBoxColumn_SelectedIndexChanged);
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(m_ComboBoxColumn_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }

    private void m_ComboBoxColumn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
        string item = comboBox.Text;
        if (item != null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item); // This is the new item text
            // Now I need the row index of this ComboBox in 'm_GridView' (or 'm_ComboBoxColumn')
        }
    }
}
```

How can I find the row index of the ComboBox in the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in this last method?

Comment: var index = comboBox.SelectedIndex;

Comment: Could you make it more clear `row index` or `item index`? When you say `row index`, it does mean the `index` of the `DataGridViewRow` containing the current combobox

Comment: Right, so I do NOT mean the index of the selected item in the ComboBox, I need the row index of ComboBox in the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @Yellow that's clear now, see my answer for the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast it to `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl` and access the `EditingControlRowIndex` to get the row index like this:

```
var comboBox = (DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)sender;
int rowIndex = comboBox.EditingControlRowIndex;
```

Comment: And while we're at it: is there an equivalent way to find the column index in the same way, in case you had multiple columns with ComboBoxes? I noticed there is no such thing as `EditingControlColumnIndex`.

Comment: @Yellow I'm not sure but in fact you can check for the `CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` or `CurrentCellAddress.X` of the `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it via the ComboBox's SelectedIndex property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx

```
var index = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. I mean the row index of the ComboBox itself within the DataGridView. I updated the question in an attempt to make it a bit clearer.